# Spark generate occurrence matrix

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have input transactions as shown

```
apples,mangos,eggs
milk,oranges,eggs
milk, cereals
mango,apples
```

I have to generate a Spark dataframe of co-occurrence matrix like this.

```
     apple mango  milk cereals  eggs
apple    2     2      0     0       1
mango    2     2      0     0       1
milk     0     0      2     1       1
cereals  0     0      1     1       0
eggs     1     1      1     0       2
```

Apples and mango are bought twice together, so in a matrix[apple][mango] =2.

I am stuck in ideas for implementing this? Any suggestions would be great help. I am using PySpark to implement this.

Comment: what's the schema of your original data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If data looks like this:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    ["apples,mangos,eggs", "milk,oranges,eggs", "milk,cereals", "mangos,apples"],
    "string"
).toDF("basket")
```

Import

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, explode, monotonically_increasing_id
```

Split and explode:

```py
long = (df
    .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
    .select("id", explode(split("basket", ","))))
```

Self-join and corsstab

```py
long.withColumnRenamed("col", "col_").join(long, ["id"]).stat.crosstab("col_", "col").show()

# +--------+------+-------+----+------+----+-------+
# |col__col|apples|cereals|eggs|mangos|milk|oranges|
# +--------+------+-------+----+------+----+-------+
# | cereals|     0|      1|   0|     0|   1|      0|
# |    eggs|     1|      0|   2|     1|   1|      1|
# |    milk|     0|      1|   1|     0|   2|      1|
# |  mangos|     2|      0|   1|     2|   0|      0|
# |  apples|     2|      0|   1|     2|   0|      0|
# | oranges|     0|      0|   1|     0|   1|      1|
# +--------+------+-------+----+------+----+-------+
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you